# How would I add information to a specific object in a generic list?

Tags: c#, oop, generic-list

I am using Windows Forms Application.

Lets say I had instantiated a list of a class:

```
List<Tree> trees = new List<Tree>();
Tree t1 = new Tree("Evergreen");
Tree t2 = new Tree("Fern");
trees.Add(t1);
trees.Add(t2);
```

in my Tree class I have

```
protected int _height
protected string _name

public int Height{get {return _height;}protected set { _height = value;}}
public string Name{ get{return _name;}protected set {_name = value;}

Public Tree(String Name){_name = Name;} //constructor
```

I have created a form called 'Add height'

in this form contains:

```
protected int _treeHeight;

public int TreeHeight{ get{return _treeHeight;}protected set {_treeHeight = value;}
```

I have managed to get the form to display the height for example:

- create a method
- get the value from the text box
- set the value to the TreeHeight

My only issue is adding the tree height to the relevant object in the list.

How would I add the tree height to the first tree in the list?

Comment: Remove `protected` from `public int Height{get {return _height;}protected set { _height = value;}}`

Comment: `trees[0].Height = TreeHeight;`? Or what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @SBI trees doesn't exist on the seperate form

Comment: Well, then you're going to have to either make that list public (you shouldn't actually do that), or make it accessible from the outside (through a setter). It's hard to tell what the actual solution is from the limited context.

Comment: A solution would be most helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little hard to parse but if I understand it you have a form with a field that lets you modify a height and you want to assign the modified height back to a specific tree?

If this is the case the good news is that Tree is a reference object. This means getting a reference to a Tree will allow you to set the value.

This being said there are a few ways I can see this working for you. The first would be to to have your Form take in a Tree object either via the constructor or a property or something

```
public Tree { get; set; }
```

And assigning the value in your form directly.

The other way is to pull the value directly from the form after it has been displayed. Typically you would want to set Dialog.Result to OK or Cancel depending on how the form was closed. But then you would access it from the form. In your example of setting the value of the first tree in your list.

```
trees[0].Height = form.TreeHeight;
```

Note that there is no error checking that so you'd want to make sure that trees[0] exists etc. Also that only assigns the value to the first element so you would need a way to determine which element you actually are wanting to set.

Comment: the program doesn't like the constructor, I've put the constructor in the Tree class and it doesn't like there being a getter or setter.

Comment: I don't think I understand this comment. Are you getting an error or something? Also, I meant the form needs to know about the Tree class not the other way around.

Comment: I tried putting it on the form and it doesn't like there being `{ } ` or `get; set`- I put in `public Tree { get; set; }` and it doesn't like the fields

Comment: What is the error it gives you? Is Tree a private class?

Comment: I gave you the answer cause I thought your solution would have helped if I had provided a clear and concise problem. Thanks for your help in this.